# How to read float in cmd from bat file?

Tags: windows, cmd

So all I need  is just to read float from cmd input and run .exe file with this value

This is bat file:

```
Set  /P /A  f =Input f: 
Project.exe %f%
```

But this doesnt work fot int values neither. What should I change?

Comment: Remove the spaces around the equal sign, they get part of the variable name/content. Also remove the /A from the input variant - they exclude each other-

Comment: @LotPings oh, it works. Silly mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use both options `/A` and `/P` with `set` command. So, you need to modify your code, so it will look likt the following:

```bat
Set /P f=Input f: 
Project.exe %f%
```

Space between `set` and `/P` option and `f` and `=` was removed as it was not needed.